# Pseudo hover class on td element does not apply to anchor (a) tag

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a tags nested inside the td tags. Problem is, when I apply a pseudo hover class over the td tag, the a tag does not respond accordingly. Now I can apply the pseudo class to the a tag as well, but the a tag does not span the entire area of the td cell. Both my background and text color changes when hovering, now the background works fine, but the text only changes color when hovering over the a tag, which does not span the entire height of the cell. I want the text color in the a tags to change when hovering over ANY part of the td tag. here is my working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gGAW5/

Thank You very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is add a second selector to your CSS for `a:hover`:

```
#rightDiv a:hover,
#rightDiv td:hover a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2363b0;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gGAW5/1/).

This styles the `a` in its `:hover` state regardless of whether it's the `td` or just the `a` itself that's hovered over.

Comment: +1 This could be simplified to just `#rightDiv td:hover a` I believe?

Comment: This is true, but I tend to put them both together (which leads to redundancy, but makes it easier to remember what the rules are for when it comes to editing-time).

Comment: Thank you so much David, appreciated!

Comment: Check my answer. If you are hovering & changing color according to UX it means its clickable & yours is not its just changing the property not making your link clickable. Anyways, Its your choice.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what? CSS can *only* change a property, that's all it does. If the OP wants clickable links then all he has to do is fill in the `href` attributes of the links. Or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working fiddle as you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/gGAW5/9/

```
#rightDiv td{
font-size: 18px;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 10px 5px; 
border: 1px solid #000099;    
}

#rightDiv a{
color: #ffffff;
display:block;
padding: 22px 5px; 
background: url(http://v4m.mobi/php/landing/images/rightDivBack.jpg) no-repeat;    
}

#rightDiv a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color: #2363b0;
background-position: -300px 0px;
}   ​
```

**Remove `#rightDiv td:hover` style.**

Comment: thank you. this works, correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't like the padding applied, with different browser dimension rendering, it can just create problems.

Comment: No, why is that. There will be no problem on using padding or margin on elements. Just you have to use it efficiently with proper calculation. I cant say about IE6 or IE7 but i am sure it will work on  all other browser. And its working fine with Chrome 19, FF 13 & safari 5 on my MAC. Its your choice. But, its not possible to have a website witout padding & margins.

Answer (score 0):

Add `color: #2363b0;` to the `td:hover` rule.